# Locality Issue In Apache Phoenix Csv Hbase Bulkload

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

**csv bulk loading to hbase table**

*Phoenix Version* : **apache-phoenix-4.10.0-HBase-0.98-bin**
*HBASE Version*   : **hbase-0.98.16-hadoop2**

When I am bulk loading data to the hbase table(created through phoenix), locality getting reduced.
How to solve this.. one solution is giving higher replication.
Is there any other solution.